# Difference between NewEnvironment and R_NewHashedEnvironment in R's C interface

Tags: c, r

Inside of the C interface for the R language there appears to be two ways of creating environments. They are:

- [`NewEnvironment()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/memory.c#L2295)
- [`R_NewHashedEnvironment()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/envir.c#L355)

`R_NewHashedEnvironment()` seems to call `NewEnvironment()` to create the environment. So I would like to know when I would want to use one call as apposed to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's the same difference between calling

```
new.env(hash=FALSE)
```

or

```
new.env(hash=TRUE)
```

from within R (as seen [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/07ac1e21db175ac877530a5d0105906911e56c18/src/main/builtin.c#L316)).

The `?environment` help page describes the option and even provides a link to a discussion on [performance implications of hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). So if you want the names of your variables to be stored in a hash, choose `R_NewHashedEnvironment()`, if not, choose `NewEnvironment()`

Comment: So, does this mean if it's using a hash table I need to `HASHTAB()` to define a variable in the environment, where as if I didn't use one I can just use `FRAME()`?